# how to handle nested for each loop which contain callback using sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have pseudo code -

```
foreach(clients){
 foreach(orderids)
   {
    //call asynchronous findOne() 
      if(client_Has_OrderId){
       count++;
       }
    }//close foreach orderids
storeInArray(client,count);
}//close client foreach loop
```

I am new on sails.js and don't know how to code this in sails.js I have no experience of asynchronous programming.When I code this in synchronous way desire result not get.

result should look like-

```
client1 1
client2 5
client3 0
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can do using async() or Promise [bluebird]. It's not a sails.js question

Answer (score 0):

I want to recommend you to have a look at the sails [reference](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference) and also the [concepts section](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts).

It always depends on your setup: I assumed you have set up a foreign key to your orders (see [OneToMany](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-to-many)), so you can just populate your values and directly access them in the promise, which would be the optimized way to query your desired result.

ES 5 compatible code could look like:

*Note that I am using lodash (or underscore) for validating the array - which is included by default in sails.js if you did't disable it in the config.*

```js
Client.find({your:'criteria'})
  .populate('orders')
  .then(function(clients){
    
    var orderIndex = {};
    
    _.forEach(clients, function(client, index){
      
      if(!_.isArray(client.orders)) {
        orderIndex[client.id] = 0;
      } else {
        orderIndex[client.id] = client.orders.length;
    });

    // do something with [orderIndex]
    
  })
  .catch(function(e){
    console.log(e);
  })
```